# Changing CMOS battery Compaq 1234

Tags: battery, cmos, compaq-laptop

How do I locate and change the CMOS battery in HP Compaq Presario 1234?

Answer (score 0):

It's easier than you think. Just go to the official webpage and grab the maintenance manual.
Here is the [manual page](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/manualCategory?cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&product=94987&).

Grab it and check the instructions. I tried to look into it, but I couldn't find the exact location of the battery in such a short time. However, I'm perfectly confident that you can find it with ease, if you expose the mainboard.

Comment: The manual does NOT include anything about CMOS battery. It seems that "exposing the mainboard" requires brute force, and I am uncertain about that!